# Jamod Slave Example, can not connect to slave

Tags: java, tcp, modbus

I tried to execute this java modbus slave example http://pastebin.com/uLJNiscj using jamod library. I can compile the package with no errors and run it on my local PC. But when I try to connect over port 502, no connection can be established. The port is open. Other modbus master tools can be connected to my PC.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
 **InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"); // Neu** 
 if (Modbus.debug) System.out.println("Listening...");
 listener = new ModbusTCPListener(100);
 **listener.setAddress(addr);  // Neu**
```

Added the lines with comment // Neu and now it works!